# How to check if a vector of a vector exists?

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to know if a vector of vectors exist

for example

```
vector<vector<int> > edges;
```

Now I would like to check if edges[i] exists. I tried

```
if(edges[i] == NULL)
```

But it did not seem to work. How this can be resolved?

Clarification:
I tried checking the size. I am just querying if its if initialized or not.

Comment: There is no pointer here, hence `NULL` does not make sense. No offense, but you should learn the basics of objects, references and pointers in C++.

Comment: *"I would like to know if a vector of vectors exist"* - `vector<vector<int> > edges` simply exists within its scope. Take more time to express yourself.

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to check if `edges[i]` is empty:

```
if (edges[i].empty())
```

Comment: It's better to use `.empty()` if that's the condition you want to test for. Although for `std::vector<>` it won't make a difference, for other types like `std::list<>` it might.

Comment: Thanks , I tried that earlier but lets assume the edge[i] does not exist and its get queried. It will break.

Comment: It's not possible for it to not exist unless you're using `std::vector<>` incorrectly. You have to set an explicit size for the outer vector. Referencing `edges[i]` for `i >= edges.size()` is not valid.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might have confused checking whether an object "exists" which is not relevant here with bounds checking. If you want to check whether `i` is a valid index, just check if it's within the size of the vector:

```
if (i < edges.size())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [vector.empty()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty):

```
if (edges[i].empty()){
}
```

Or use [vector.size()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size):

```
if (edges[i].size() == 0){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> vector<vector<int> > edges;
> ```
>
> Now I would like to check if `edges[i]` existis.

It seems that `std::vector` is the wrong (outer) data type for you. Perhaps you should use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) instead:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> edges;

if (edges.find(i) == edges.end()) {
  // does not exist
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` (or more correctly, since you tagged C++11, `nullptr`) is used for checking pointers. You've declared a `vector` of concrete instances, so pointers don't apply, and if the test

```
if (i < edges.size())
```

then the `vector` is *initialized* - that is, constructed. You can check, next, whether it is populated:

```
if (i < edges.size() && !edges[i].empty())
```

however, this will not distinguish between uninitialized and currently empty, consider:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.pop_back(); // now it's empty again

bool uninitialized = v.empty(); // lies
```

It *is* empty, but it has been initialized and used, if that is your definition of initialized.

There is, however, one trick left, but it is tending towards undefined behavior.

```
if (i < edges.size() && edges[i].capacity() == 0)
```

This will tell you if the `vector` has any memory allocated. In the worst case scenario, if your `vector` aggressively frees, it will be equivalent to `empty()`. But in most standard implementations, a vector that has been populated will have non-zero capacity, whilst a vector that has not yet been used will have no capacity.

Again: it's not perfect, there are ways to tell the vector to release any capacity it has.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly then the only way you get a guaranteed behavior is, if you manage the state of the vector initialization yourself in a separate boolean variable?